# Error when trying to build flutter app for ios

Tags: flutter

When I run flutter for my physical iOS device it fails to build. I have tried to resolve the problem using `flutter clean`.

> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> /Users/arhanbusam/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.m:88:37:
> warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'FlutterEngine *' to
> parameter of type
> 'NSObject * _Nonnull' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> binaryMessenger:_headlessEngine];
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> In module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/arhanbusam/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.h:2:
> /Users/arhanbusam/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:178:74:
> note: passing argument to parameter 'messenger' here
> binaryMessenger:(NSObject*)messenger;
> ^
> /Users/arhanbusam/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.m:417:74:
> warning: 'initWithImage:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
>
> - Use
>   -initWithBoundsSize:requestHandler: [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>   MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: artworkImage];
>   ^
>   In module 'MediaPlayer' imported from /Users/arhanbusam/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.m:7:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/Headers/MPMediaItem.h:240:1:
>   note: 'initWithImage:'
>   has been explicitly marked deprecated here
>
>   - (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image MP_DEPRECATED("Use -initWithBoundsSize:requestHandler:", ios(5.0, 10.0));
>     ^
>     2 warnings generated.
>     warning: MinimumOSVersion of '9.0' is less than the value of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET '13.0' - setting to '13.0'. (in target
>     'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>     building file list ... done
>     App.framework/
>     App.framework/App
>     App.framework/Info.plist
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/AssetManifest.json
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/FontManifest.json
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/NOTICES
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/isolate_snapshot_data
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/vm_snapshot_data
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/sound1.mp3
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/sound2.mp3
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/
>     App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf
>
>   sent 40468200 bytes  received 348 bytes  26979032.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 40462062  speedup is 1.00
>   building file list ... done
>   Flutter.framework/
>   Flutter.framework/Flutter
>   Flutter.framework/Info.plist
>   Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
>
>   sent 64435719 bytes  received 92 bytes  42957207.33 bytes/sec
>   total size is 64427549  speedup is 1.00
>   /Users/arhanbusam/Dropbox/Documents/Arhan-Flutter/simple_exercise_timer/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Exercise
>   Timer.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: signed bundle with Mach-O thin
>   (arm64)
>   [io.flutter.flutter.app]
>   /Users/arhanbusam/Dropbox/Documents/Arhan-Flutter/simple_exercise_timer/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Exercise
>   Timer.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: signed bundle with
>   Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64)
>   [io.flutter.flutter]
>   /Users/arhanbusam/Dropbox/Documents/Arhan-Flutter/simple_exercise_timer/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Exercise
>   Timer.app/Info.plist: Could not extract value, error: No value at that
>   key path or invalid key
>   path: NSBonjourServices
>   /Users/arhanbusam/Dropbox/Documents/Arhan-Flutter/simple_exercise_timer/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Exercise
>   Timer.app/Info.plist: Could not extract value, error: No value at that
>   key path or invalid key
>   path: NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/cp", line 5, in 
>   from run.cp_run import cp_start
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/cp_run.py",
>   line 1, in 
>   from settings.*first_load* import check_if_first_time
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/settings/*first_load*.py",
>   line 114, in 
>   check_if_first_time()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/settings/*first_load*.py",
>   line 108, in check_if_first_time
>   first_time()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/settings/*first_load*.py",
>   line 70, in first_time
>   confirm = input()
>   EOFError: EOF when reading a line
>   Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
>   note: Using new build system
>   note: Building targets in parallel
>   note: Planning build
>   note: Constructing build description
>
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Comment: Are you using a mac system?

Comment: Yes I am @yahyaparvar